# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, django

newbie here. I [copy](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/204197-solving-the-metaclass-conflict/) this python recipe, but with errors when I try to run on my django

```
def get_noconflict_metaclass(bases, left_metas, right_metas):
    """Not intended to be used outside of this module, unless you know
    what you are doing."""
    # make tuple of needed metaclasses in specified priority order
    metas = left_metas + tuple(map(type, bases)) + right_metas
    needed_metas = remove_redundant(metas)
```

**ERROR**

Here are the values:

```
left_metas (<class 'ccad.admin.ModelAdminWithForeignKeyLinksMetaclass'>,)
right_metas ()
...
 File "/opt/myenv/myproject/ccad/admin.py", line 201, in 
class SOAdetailAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
 File "/opt/myenv/myproject/ccad/noconflict.py", line 52, in make_class
def make_class(name, bases, adict):
 File "/opt/myenv/myproject/ccad/noconflict.py", line 30, in get_noconflict_metaclass
metas = left_metas + tuple(map(type(), bases,),) + right_metas
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'tuple'
```

I can't find the problem.

**Input Params**

```
'''
I'm using this snippet to show Foreign keys in django admin list display
'''
class ModelAdminWithForeignKeyLinksMetaclass(MediaDefiningClass):

def __getattr__(cls, name):

    def foreign_key_link(instance, field):
        target = getattr(instance, field)
        return u'<a href="../../%s/%s/%d">%s</a>' % (
            target._meta.app_label, target._meta.module_name, target.id, unicode(target))

    if name[:8] == 'link_to_':
        method = partial(foreign_key_link, field=name[8:])
        method.__name__ = name[8:]
        method.allow_tags = True
        setattr(cls, name, method)
        return getattr(cls, name)
    raise AttributeError
##############################################
```

And I tried to used this in my admin.py

```
from noconflict import classmaker
class SOAdetailAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    __metaclass__ = classmaker(ModelAdminWithForeignKeyLinksMetaclass)
```

Comment: what are the values of `left_metas` and `right_metas` ?

Comment: can you print left_metas and right_metas before adding them ?

Comment: @Charlesliasm please give your input params to this question

Comment: 'newbie'?? working with metaclasses?

Comment: yes, my first encounter with metaclass. I usually used meta in django

Comment: @karthikr, here's my the value: left_metas <class 'ccad.admin.ModelAdminWithForeignKeyLinksMetaclass'>, right_metas ()

Comment: left_metas should probably a tuple, try to convert it by using `left_metas = left_metas,` <- note the trailing comma

Comment: yes, indeed the values were: left_metas (<class 'ccad.admin.ModelAdminWithForeignKeyLinksMetaclass'>,) and right_metas ()

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the comments. It really help point out what should I do.

### From snippet author explanation and example:

Here the problem is that since D inherits from A, its metaclass must inherit from M_A and cannot be M_B.

classmaker solves the problem by automatically inheriting both from M_A and M_B:

```
>>> class D(A):
...     __metaclass__=classmaker(right_metas=(M_B,))
>>> type(D)
```

I change my original code to this and django is working fine:

```
class SOAdetailAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    __metaclass__ = classmaker(right_metas=(ModelAdminWithForeignKeyLinksMetaclass,))
```